# React front end for Wordpress API - Adding content.rendered Only secure origins are allowed

Tags: wordpress, api, reactjs, ssl, https

Just as a preface, I am using create-react-app boiler plate.

I am trying to parse out a post from the wordpress API into a react component so I can extract all images and make them their own JSX objects. I need to have each post have its own on click method so I cant just use the dangerouslyaddHTML function in React.

Currently, I search through the string of json that had the rendered HTML from the WP content of each post and find all img tags. I then add then image src to an array and set this in my state.

However I am getting this error :

**DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed**

The site I have this currently hosted on it http://natalie.madeline-omoore.com/build/

The code for part of my component is below:

```
`componentDidMount(){
var owner;
for(var i = 0; i < this.props.categoryId.length; i++) {
    if (this.props.categoryId[i].num === this.props.content.categories[0]) {
        owner = this.props.categoryId[i].category;
        this.setState({
          catname: owner
        })
        break;
    }        
}
var theContent = this.props.content.content.rendered;

var output = $(theContent).find("img").map(function() {
  return this.src;

}).get();



this.setState({
  postImages: output
});

   }
  click(){
    this.updateActive();
    this.props.fix();
  }


 render() {
if (this.props.className === this.state.catname) {
   return (
    <div >
      { this.props.className === this.state.catname && 
        <article className={`${this.state.catname}`} >
             {this.state.postImages.map((image, i) => 
                <ImageContain key={image} image={image} fix={this.props.fix} />
             )}

      </article>
     } 
   </div>
  );
 } else {
    return null;
 }

}`
```

I am new to react so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with the 'service worker' that is default with create-react-app

You can deregister the worker by adding the following to index.js:

```
import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';

// ...

unregister();
```

Be sure to call unregister() after registerServiceWorker() is called.

You can learn more about this here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#making-a-progressive-web-app

Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: I should also note that adding SSL to your Wordpress website would also likely fix the issue, and would be less of a bandaid on the problem.



I recommend Certbot for getting SSL. It uses letsencrypt, it's free, and they have great documentation: https://certbot.eff.org/